# Derived Contract unable to deploy

Tags: solidity, remix

For the following stripped down version of my code.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

contract Managers{

    struct Manager{
        uint index;
        bool isHead;
        bool isManager;
    }

    mapping(address => Manager) managerAddresses;
    address[] public managerAddressesArr;

    modifier isHead(address sender){
        require(managerAddresses[sender].isHead);
        _;
    }

    modifier isManager(address sender){
        require(managerAddresses[sender].isManager);
        _;
    }

    constructor(address[] _managerAddresses) public{
        for(uint i=0;i<_managerAddresses.length;i++){
            managerAddresses[_managerAddresses[i]] = Manager(i,false,true);
        }
        managerAddresses[msg.sender] = Manager(managerAddressesArr.length,true,false);
        managerAddressesArr = _managerAddresses;
        managerAddressesArr.push(msg.sender);
    }


}

contract UploadFactory is Managers{


}
```

I am unable to deploy the uploadFactory contract using remix. I keep getting the error

> This contract does not implement all functions and thus cannot be
>   created.

When I deploy the uploadFactory contract.

If you want to see the full code you can find it here but the problem is the same.

https://ethfiddle.com/cFVgjmQJwW

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define the constructor in the UploadFactory in order to deploy, since is defined in the parent class

```
contract UploadFactory is Managers{
    constructor(address[] _managerAddresses) public Managers(_managerAddresses) {}
}
```

this will work

Comment: Thank you! So derived call constructors have to be the same as the parent?

Comment: You can add parameters and define its own behavior, but still you need to reflect the parent class and call its constructor to deploy it.